# Is Plone or Drupal more appropriate for heavy JavaScript integration?

Tags: javascript, drupal, plone

While I imagine that a definitive answer would require more specifics, I'm interested in a high-level perspective about the appropriateness of heavy JavaScript integration in either cms.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to answer the question you actually asked — rather than the question you may have meant — by focussing on "appropriateness." In my mind, js integration is appropriate when 1) it actually improves usability, and is not simply decorative; 2) is done with careful attention to maintaining accessibility; 3) is done in a javascript integration layer that achieves separateness from the content layer and modularity in implementation; and 4) minimizes page-load impact.

In regard to Plone, all I can say is that we've spent a lot of time on these issues, and that our framework team is aggressive in demanding that we meet those tests before integrating new functionality. I'm in particular proud of how we're doing on accessibility, and expect us to continue to focus on that. We won't deliberately break accessibility, and if we break it accidentally, we're going to fix it.

One very tough area is consistency. We've been bounced around between choosing between consistency within the platform's use of JS and choosing individual tools as best-of-breed for a particular functionality. I can't say we've done well on either score. The results are OK, but it gives the new developer a burden to understand the toolbox.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more specific--wasn't sure if it was of interest. I'm referring to integrating several visual tools into the cms.  For example, allowing users to synchronously create/edit a concept-map/bubble-map with aid of XMPP services.  Allow them to move a slider to scale the image somewhat like a prezi tool.  Also, allow user info or info from some object in the site to be shown upon mouse-over of a bubble for example.  Making a tool where a gantt chart can be connected to a calendar view.

Comment: I think you're going to discover that both platforms provide all the support you need to integrate that sort of functionality fairly easily so long as the JS you want to use is jQuery compatible. Check in at IRC channels or add-on listings to see if anyone's already done the particular work for you.

Comment: A good example of a recent, very sophisticated XMPP-integration project: http://plone.org/products/jarn.xmpp.core

Comment: XMPP is hopefully the way we can achieve synchronicity in the bubble-mapping so very cool.  I hope some Drupal folks can weigh in on this question.

Answer (score 4):

Plone has integrated portal_javascripts registry which allows you to

- Merge and compress Javascript files to bundles
- Set "safe compress" flags per file etc.
- Set conditions when Javascript files are served (only for authenticated users)
- Use IE conditional includes
- etc.

i.e. it's very heavy tool for Javascript processing and supported out of the box.
All this can be edited dynamically through-the-web in admin interface. This is far superior tool compared to manually adding your files to `<head>` or using an external tool to manage Javascript compression bundles.

Plone also sets Expires headers and generates cache busting URLs for JS files correctly, something many CMS lack out-of-the-box.

More info can be found by

1) Install Plone

2) Go to Zope Management Interfcae

3) Find portal_javascripts

Comment: As a heavily front end weighted developer, I am very happy with Plone

Comment: Thanks for further details Mikko--it would be great to get some Drupal folks to weigh in...